# Overriding a service found through Java discovery mechanism

Tags: java, service-discovery

Situation: we use a library that provides implementation of some Java interface and makes it available through standard Java service discovery mechanism. I.e. in its JAR there is a file `META-INF/services/foo.bar.InterfaceFoo` with text `com.library.FooImpl` in it.

The implementation is generally fine, but still we'd like to add some extensions. It's a public non-final class, so we just subclass it, and make our subclass discoverable too, by adding `META-INF/services/foo.bar.InterfaceFoo` in our application with text `com.us.ourapplication.OurOwnFooImpl`, where `OurOwnFooImpl` extends `com.library.FooImpl`.

The problem now is that *both* versions are visible through discovery mechanism. Moreover, (external and non-alterable) instantiation code adds discovered implementations to a `HashSet`, so the order is completely random, i.e. whether ours or original is first cannot be controlled.

**Question:**
Can we somehide hide library's implementation from discovery mechanism without hacking its JAR?